# Edit extension using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension to block images.
I want to block two file types.
Current code works fine for blocking Gif image.

```
  documentUrlPatterns: ['*://*/*'],
  targetUrlPatterns: ['*://*/*.gif*']
```

How can I block PNG and Gif images? I mean how can edit the Regex code?I want add another file type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome uses [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns) rather than regular expressions in [this API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus). So it's not possible to capture both .gif and .png in a single match pattern. However, because it's an array, you can include multiple patterns, for example:

```
targetUrlPatterns: ['*://*/*.gif', '*://*/*.png']
```

Comment: Its Ok.
But the better way is this : targetUrlPatterns: ['*://*/*.(gif|jpg|png)*']

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited Unfortunately I don't believe that's a supported URL pattern syntax. You can see the Chromium source code uses the same definition as in the [documentation that I linked](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns) -  https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/url_pattern.h?sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&g=0